# System.DirectoryServices use And limitation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, active-directory

In my application I need to fetch users email from Active Directory.

I came across the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace for accessing Active Directory. I have no idea on how it works. I have few questions.

Can I simply use this namespace and access AD with proper queries? Is there any pre-requisite 
like access to LDAP etc.

Please let me know how this actually works

FYI I use .net 4.0

Answer (score 1):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   // find a user
   UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

   if(user != null)
   {
      // do something here....      
   }

   // find the group in question
   GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

   // if found....
   if (group != null)
   {
       // iterate over members
       foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
       {
          Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);
          // do whatever you need to do to those members
       }
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!